# System can't write in the windows mounted location

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, mountpoint

I have a shared directory on a Windows server and mounted it on Ubuntu 14.04 server with this command,

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.137/data$ /mnt/data
```

I mounted the directory using sudo as the system did not allow me to mount from my Ubuntu user. The windows server doesn't need any username or password to access this directory.

Now the problem is, that only the root user can write files into this directory and I need all system users to write in this directory. I followed few articles but they weren't useful for cifs shares.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `ll /mnt`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have and drop me a note @Fabby

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, let's make your Ubuntu Login a sudo user.

```
 sudo usermod -U username
```

And try to mount it from the User.